# Automounting with udev

Tags: linux, automation, automount, udev, udevd

Currently my distribution of choice (ArchLinux) has an automounting script like this:

```
KERNEL!="sd[a-z][0-9]", GOTO="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"
```

But that will automount only partitions up to sdX9. I do have USB drives with 6 or more partitions (that is, starting from 5, up to 12, 13, 19).

All partitions have VFAT on them and have labels (the label is used for naming the mountpoint).

I have tried to modify it to:

```
KERNEL!="sd[a-z][0-9]+", GOTO="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"
```

but that doesn't work.

So how to make it work for sdb5, sdb42 or sdb31337 likewise?

Thanks.

**Addendum**

I've just tried the `\d+?` method, udevadm monitor says:

```
KERNEL[1295719513.473653] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host29/target29:0:0/29:0:0:0/block/sdb (block)
KERNEL[1295719513.473687] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host29/target29:0:0/29:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb1 (block)
KERNEL[1295719513.473706] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host29/target29:0:0/29:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb5 (block)
KERNEL[1295719513.473725] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host29/target29:0:0/29:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb6 (block)
KERNEL[1295719513.473743] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host29/target29:0:0/29:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb7 (block)
KERNEL[1295719513.473761] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host29/target29:0:0/29:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb8 (block)
KERNEL[1295719513.473791] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host29/target29:0:0/29:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb9 (block)
KERNEL[1295719513.473811] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host29/target29:0:0/29:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb10 (block)
KERNEL[1295719513.473830] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host29/target29:0:0/29:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb11 (block)
KERNEL[1295719513.473848] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host29/target29:0:0/29:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb12 (block)

UDEV  [1295719513.593213] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host29/target29:0:0/29:0:0:0/block/sdb (block)
UDEV  [1295719514.959983] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host29/target29:0:0/29:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb5 (block)
UDEV  [1295719514.960053] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host29/target29:0:0/29:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb1 (block)
UDEV  [1295719514.961528] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host29/target29:0:0/29:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb6 (block)
UDEV  [1295719514.963793] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host29/target29:0:0/29:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb9 (block)
UDEV  [1295719514.964930] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host29/target29:0:0/29:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb10 (block)
UDEV  [1295719514.965794] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host29/target29:0:0/29:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb12 (block)
UDEV  [1295719514.967418] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host29/target29:0:0/29:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb8 (block)
UDEV  [1295719514.968466] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host29/target29:0:0/29:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb7 (block)
UDEV  [1295719514.973757] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host29/target29:0:0/29:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb11 (block)
```

But it doesn't work either. If I leave the default rule, sdb5-9 are mounted properly.

Answer (score 1):

`KERNEL!="sd[a-z]\d+?", GOTO="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I'm using udevd version 165. See the addendum in my question for details.